# pipx install eth-brownie issue

Tags: python, pip, solidity, brownie, pipx

Trying to install eth-brownie with pipx as recommended on Windows through powershell terminal in Visual Studio Code. Tried reinstalling pip and pipx. No problems installing eth-brownie through pip, but need it done through pipx. Below is the error message:

```
PS C:\Users\XXX\OneDrive\Desktop\Blockchain-101\demos\brownie_simple_storage> pipx install eth-brownie

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\roaming\python\python310\scripts\pipx.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pipx\main.py", line 779, in cli
    return run_pipx_command(parsed_pipx_args)
  File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pipx\main.py", line 202, in run_pipx_command
    return commands.install(
  File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pipx\commands\install.py", line 60, in install
    venv.install_package(
  File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pipx\venv.py", line 238, in install_package
    subprocess_post_check_handle_pip_error(pip_process)
  File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pipx\util.py", line 349, in subprocess_post_check_handle_pip_error
    print(completed_process.stderr, file=pip_error_fh, end="")
  File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2502' in position 559: character maps to <undefined>
```

Could anyone help me understand where this issue is coming from and how to fix it?

Comment: Any update on this one? I am stuck with this one as well. I have tried different things like the author himself, however no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Right, I know it is not ideal solution, however I got passed through this step.
I fresh installed python 3.10.2. Afterwards, I visited the eth-brownie page:

https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install.html

and installed brownie, following GitHub method specified in 'Other Installation Methods' section.